# Android Inject in webview external js, execute function, and raise an alert

Tags: javascript, android, webview, alert

I want to inject an external javascript in webview and execute one of its functions `execute()`. After completion an alert is raised and the string returns to the activity
this is how I do it but it doesn't seem to work (the js is already tested)

`view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { var script=document.createElement('script');script.type='text/javascript';script.src=" + jsFileURL + ";" + "document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(script);window.HTMLOUT.showHTML(execute());})()");`

this is how I implement HTMLOUT, while the alert is overrided in ChromeClient

`browser.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");    browser.setWebViewClient(new mWebViewClient());    browser.setWebChromeClient(new mChromeClient());    browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Travian comx2b.htm");`

Answer (score 3):

Ok after many many attempts I found a workaround, but unfortunately not the "solution".  I used this load  `view.loadUrl("javascript:" + src + "    execute();  " + "");`    while the source `src` comes from a text file `script.js` which includes my javascript (both functions and plain commands)

```
//get script
InputStream is;
        String src= "";
        try {
            is = getAssets().open("travianbot.js");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            // Convert the buffer into a string.
            src = new String(buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

a sample of the script.js (be careful on line endings ";")

```
function addItem(v, link, x, y, result) {
    //function commands  
}
function popup() {
    alert(execute().split("@"));
}     
function execute(){  
    //function commands
    additem(...);
}
// plain commands
.......
```

One resolution for a remote script, which I haven't tested it, is to parse the remote script (e.g. as inputstream) and then included it as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

I think u have to enclose the jsFileUrl in single quotes.

```
script.src='" + jsFileURL + "';"
```

Comment: No I have done this along with many other tests. I have to say that once out of ten attempts it worked but that's all. I suppose there are also other issues that prevent a stable load. Next I have posted a work around.

Answer (score 0):

please check out this http://lexandera.com/2009/01/adding-alert-support-to-a-webview/

Thanks

Comment: This was the example that I was based on, however is not what I want to do.